# Data model for Stripe payments in Firestore

Tags: firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am following a tutorial (https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/collect-payments-with-angular-stripe-checkout-and-firebase/) provided by Google for using Stipe with RTDB and trying to adapt the example for use with Firestore.

The tutorial makes the following call to add data to RTDB:

```
const payment = { token, amount }
return this.db.list(`/payments/${this.userId}`).push(payment)
```

My best guess for how I would do this in Firestore is:

```
const payment = {token, 'price':this.props.price}
var db = firebase.firestore()
db.collection('payments').doc(this.props.uid).collection('test').add(payment)
```

Notice that I have the 'test' collection because Firestore requires that you alternate between docs and collections. I this the proper way to structure my data in Firestore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar situation crop up when I moved my Stripe payments data from Realtime to Firestore.

The way I got around it was to have my top-level collection being *users*, each document is a *user uid* and the each user document has a collection of payments which I add new payments into this collection.

I preferred this method than having a field as an array as it's easier to query.

Example:

```
db.collection('users').doc(this.props.uid).collection('payments').add(payment);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the same structure showed in the example:

```
payments<collection>
    userId<doc>
        paymentId<field> : [
                            amount: number
                            token: object
                            charge: object 
                           ]
```

Please note that token here is treated as a Map. Does this solution fits your needs?

Comment: I tried implementing this idea but run into an issue. Here is what I tried running:

 `db.collection('payments').doc(this.props.uid).update({
        paymentId: payment
      })`

Comment: What's the issue? Is it a design one (you want achieve something else) or you get an error?

Comment: I was able to see data but now I hit a new problem: it is not clear to me how to make paymentId dynamic when I update the doc with the new field. Currently my firestore database has field '{paymentId}' `const payment = {token, 'price':this.props.price}
      const paymentId = token.id
      var db = firebase.firestore()
      db.collection('payments').doc(this.props.uid).set({
        '{paymentId}': payment
      }, { merge: true })`.